# Performing Relational Query on Mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, algorithm, mongodb-query, rdbms

I have two collections. One named events and another named applications.
Applications contains user application data for paticular event.
I want to find those events in which user has not applied.

NOTE:
1. eventId field in applications is DBRef to events collection.
2. userId field in applications is DBRef to users collection.
3. A user can only apply single time to an event.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Events:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d07c45fabb5c771f8a81228"),
        "fee" : 400
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d07c461abb5c771f8a81229"),
        "fee" : 500
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d07c463abb5c771f8a8122a"),
        "fee" : 700
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d07c466abb5c771f8a8122b"),
        "fee" : 800
    }
]
```

Applications:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d07c4e8abb5c771f8a8122c"),
        "eventId" : ObjectId("5d07c45fabb5c771f8a81228"),
        "userId" : ObjectId("5d07c45fabb5c772f8a81978"),
        "text" : "I am interested"
    }
]
```

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook/manual with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show what relevant parts you can do & explain re the first place you are stuck.

Comment: @philipxy I have already accomplished this tas using MongoDB aggregations earlier, OK. I just wanted to know if anybody has an optimized solution. Now if you are new to a database and only way to retrieve the data is a query and you are unable to create a query for the same, how am I supposed to show some results or query when they are of no use (or may mislead) other users.

Comment: "Show what relevant parts you can do & explain re the first place you are stuck." PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stage 1: $lookup - Used to join events and applications collections

Stage 2: $match - Filter the events that don't have any user application

```
[
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'applications', 
            'localField': '_id', 
            'foreignField': 'eventId', 
            'as': 'eventsApps'
        }
    }, {
        '$match': {
            '$expr': {
                '$lte': [
                    {
                        '$size': '$eventsApps'
                    }, 0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you. Earlier I was doing it in a way that, I would retrieve event ids' from the 'applications' collection and then query events collection with '$nin'